# Submit posts blank data into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I'm really new to this, I'm having a problem and it's been hurting my brain for the last few days, I have tried searching my problem and things but nothing is working.

The problem is, I have an HTML form which posts data into a mysql table when you click submit, It submits the data fine however every time you press submit it submits a set of data where all the fields are blank apart from the `customer` field which corresponds to $session_user_id.

I have tried the ' if isset ' but it seems to have no effect on the code. It's probably something small that I'm missing but I'm getting no errors. My code is below, the database connection is in another .php file and is working correctly.

```
<?php

if ( isset($session_user_id, $_POST['description'])){

$description = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']));

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `jobs` (customer, description) 
    VALUES ('".$session_user_id."', '".$description."')");

}

?>
```

and my html form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <textarea name="description" rows=5 cols=30></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: You shouldn't escape the data going into the database.  You should instead escape it right before outputting it to the browser (assuming it's in an HTML context of course).  Also, if you were to escape it going into the DB, you'd do the functions in the opposite order.  escape(entities()) not entities(escape()).  Also, you should consider switching to PDO.  The msyql extension is ancient and suggested against by PHP.  Anyway, to the point, have you tried var_dump'ing $_POST['description']?  Is it an empty string?  An empty string is considered true for isset.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `htmlentities` cause works fine only with specific charsets. Check it also [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).